# Could not run the cron file in Ubuntu server using PHP

Tags: 14.04, php, cron

I have setup the cron job on Ubuntu server but it seems not running because no result is coming within the given time interval. I am explaining my command below.

```
crontab -e

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/public_html/spesh/mobileapi/specialcron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here I need to run that PHP file in every 1 min time interval but it seems not running.

Comment: Is this php file running in terminal without issues ?

Comment: Yes, while running this php file via terminal my required result is coming as expected but inside cron its not working.

Answer (score 0):

As you said the php script is running fine in termnial and you want to run the cronjob in every minute, please edit your cronjob as follows.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/public_html/spesh/mobileapi/specialcron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours)

Comment: I have tried this but its not working.

Comment: can you try editing crontab as root by typing `sudo crontab -e` and check ?

Comment: yes  I did as per you and there is no such type path I found. But when I am doing  `crontab  -e` it is there.

Comment: I did as per you still same issue.

Comment: my last try would be creating a shell script which contains the php command to execute and add execute permission to it. after that put that script in cronjob.

Comment: Also checking `/var/log/syslog` for error log of cronjob also a good idea to resolve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69497/discussion-between-satya-and-rooney).

Comment: Hi, just a suggestion. To see what might go wrong you should definetly remove > /dev/null 2>&1 for testing. Cron should send an email to the root account, showing the results of the script. But you are suppressing the output.

Comment: @s1mmel's suggestion is best: don't /dev/null the error output when you're looking for an error! I'm guessing it's an environment issue. `cron` jobs run with different environments and paths (and maybe even a different shell) than your command line.